# Для чего используется замыкание

Tags: php

В одном из методов класса (DI) Pimple, используется анонимная функция:

```
public static function share($callable)
{
    if (!is_object($callable) || !method_exists($callable, '__invoke')) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Service definition is not a Closure or invokable object.');
    }
    return function ($c) use ($callable) {
        static $object;
        if (null === $object) {
            $object = $callable($c);
        }
        return $object;
    };
}
```

Какую задачу в этом методе решает замыкание? Для чего нужная в этом случае?

Comment: Тут создается функция-враппер, похоже реализуется singleton-фабрика. Она должна ссылаться на оборачиваемую функцию - вот на нее и ссылается через замыкание.

Comment: Спасибо! Насколько я понял, это и есть singleton фабрика, реализованная в DI-контейнере.

Можно чуть подробнее пожалуйста, что имеется ввиду "функция-враппер", или пример понятный?

Comment: Вы передаете туда свою функцию-фабрику объекта, а приведенный код возвращает свою функцию, которая ссылается на переданную функцию. При этом он никак не использовал вашу функцию, а просто "обернул" в другую добавив поведение синглтона.Такие вещи называют "wrapper" или "decorator".

Comment: @vitidev, Use the Answer, Luke